# Issue with designing loop in R for executing simple linear regression equation

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression

The general form of the equation is

```
Sector ~ Beta_0 + Beta_1*absMkt + Beta_2*sqMkt
```

where Sector are the daily stock returns of each of the 12 sectors i.e AUTO ; IT ; REALTY ; BANK ; ENERGY ; FINANCIAL SERVICES ; FMCG ; INFRASTRUCTURE ; SERVICES ; MEDIA ; METAL and PHARMA.

Beta_0 is the intercept; Beta_1 is the coefficient of absolute market return; Beta_2 is the coefficient of the squared market return.

For each sector, I would like to run linear regression, where I want to extract the coefficients Beta_1 and Beta_2 if the corresponding p-value is less than 0.05 and store it.

Sample data is stated below.

It is also available for download from my google drive location

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16XUq8_lXXtD2BSlUdDAAWeHiWIznf--c?usp=share_link

Name of the file :  Week_1_CSV.csv

[image]

Code that I have tried from my end, but not getting the result

```
# Reading the data
Returns <- read.csv("Week_1_CSV.CSV", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Splitting the Data into Sector and Market Returns
Sector_Returns <- Returns[,2:13]
Market_Returns <- Returns[,14:15]

# Defining the number of sectors
nc <- ncol(Sector_Returns)

# Creating a matrix with zero value to store the coefficient values and their corresponding p-values

Beta_1 <- Beta_2 <- p_1 <- p_2 <- matrix(0, 1, nc)  # coefs and p values

# Converting the Sectoral Returns into a Matrix named "Sect_Ret_Mat"

Sect_Ret_Mat <- as.matrix(Sector_Returns)
head(Sect_Ret_Mat)

# Converting the Market Returns into a Matrix named "Mkt_Ret_Mat"

Mkt_Ret_Mat <- as.matrix(Market_Returns)
head(Mkt_Ret_Mat)

#### Without Loop ##############

mode1_lm <- lm(Sect_Ret_Mat[,1] ~ Mkt_Ret_Mat[,1] + Mkt_Ret_Mat[,2] )
summary(mode1_lm)

 # Extracting the p-value

coef(summary(mode1_lm))[2, 4] ## p-value corresponding to Beta_1
coef(summary(mode1_lm))[3, 4] ## p-value corresponding to Beta_2

# Extracting the Coefficient

coef(mode1_lm)[[2]] ## Coeficient corresponding to Beta_1
coef(mode1_lm)[[3]] ## Coeficient corresponding to Beta_2

##############################################################################

#### WithLoop ##############

for (i in 1:nc) {
  for (j in 1:nc) {
    if (i != j) {
      mode1_lm <- lm(Sect_Ret_Mat[,i] ~ Mkt_Ret_Mat[,1] + Mkt_Ret_Mat[,2] )
      p_0[i,j] <- coef(summary(mode1_lm))[2, 4]
      p_1[i,j] <- coef(summary(mode1_lm))[3, 4]
      if 
      (p_0[i, j] < 0.05) 
        Beta_0[i,j] <- coef(mode1_lm)[[2]]
     if
      (p_1[i, j] < 0.05) 
        Beta_1[i,j] <- coef(mode1_lm)[[3]]
    
    }
  }
}

Beta_0

Beta_1
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, I don't download datasets from a link. You should try to make a small example that can be easily run on anyone's computer. When running a bunch of regressions for different groups, I find it easiest to keep everything in one dataframe and avoid loops. The general workflow goes: 1) nest data by group, 2) run regression for each group, 3) use `broom` to make the coefficients into a nice table, 4) unnest the model coefficients into a table. Here is an example using `mtcars`. I show how to run a regression for each group of `cyl`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |>
  nest(data = -cyl) |>
  mutate(mod = map(data, ~lm(mpg~wt + hp, data = .x)),
         summ = map(mod, broom::tidy)) |>
  select(-data, -mod) |>
  unnest(summ)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 6
#>     cyl term        estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     6 (Intercept)  32.6       5.57        5.84 0.00428  
#> 2     6 wt           -3.24      1.37       -2.36 0.0776   
#> 3     6 hp           -0.0222    0.0202     -1.10 0.333    
#> 4     4 (Intercept)  45.8       4.79        9.58 0.0000117
#> 5     4 wt           -5.12      1.60       -3.19 0.0128   
#> 6     4 hp           -0.0905    0.0436     -2.08 0.0715   
#> 7     8 (Intercept)  26.7       3.66        7.28 0.0000158
#> 8     8 wt           -2.18      0.721      -3.02 0.0117   
#> 9     8 hp           -0.0137    0.0107     -1.27 0.229
```

Answer (score 0):

Melt your data long, and apply a helper function each sector:

1. Set dataframe `wk1` to data.table, and melt long

```
library(data.table)
setDT(wk1)


wk1 = melt(
  data = wk1[, id:=.I],
  id = c("id", "Date", "ABSOLUTE MARKLET RETURN", "SQUARED MARKET RETURN"),
  variable.name = "sector"
)
```

2. Write helper functiont that runs model and returns beta and p.value in list

```
f <- function(v,a,s) {
  cf = summary(lm(v~a+s))$coefficients[-1,]
  list(est = cf[,1],pvalue=cf[,4])
}
```

3. Apply `f` to each sector

```
wk1[, f(value, `ABSOLUTE MARKLET RETURN`, `SQUARED MARKET RETURN`), sector]
```

Output:

```
                sector         beta       pvalue
 1:               AUTO   0.71847599 1.837679e-02
 2:               AUTO  -7.44556841 3.921574e-01
 3:                 IT   0.33384211 2.878851e-02
 4:                 IT  -1.69884185 6.970822e-01
 5:             REALTY   0.19224293 3.128459e-01
 6:             REALTY   0.63655626 9.084056e-01
 7:               BANK   0.72886921 4.544867e-06
 8:               BANK -15.07590018 6.835331e-04
 9:             ENERGY   0.30568300 5.611571e-01
10:             ENERGY  -0.42252869 9.780039e-01
11: FINANCIAL SERVICES   0.46149507 1.940130e-04
12: FINANCIAL SERVICES  -2.72192333 4.238560e-01
13:               FMCG   0.38259697 1.398654e-02
14:               FMCG  -0.45504587 9.180342e-01
15:     INFRASTRUCTURE   0.28891493 1.845572e-01
16:     INFRASTRUCTURE   0.03244222 9.958937e-01
17:           SERVICES   0.49497910 2.098375e-06
18:           SERVICES  -6.52723131 2.036243e-02
19:              MEDIA   0.10040065 7.554367e-01
20:              MEDIA   0.26014494 9.779231e-01
21:              METAL   0.45139509 1.576446e-02
22:              METAL  -6.87462275 1.991497e-01
23:             PHARMA   0.39993847 1.781434e-02
24:             PHARMA  -0.74201727 8.772388e-01
```